# How to redirect URL to another URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I tried the following code to redirect one URL to another.

```
 # 301 Redirect URLs.
 Redirect 301 /sat http://sample.org/example
 Redirect 301 /gre http://sample.org/example
 Redirect 301 /ielts-sat http://sample.org/example
 Redirect 301 /ielts http://sample.org/example
```

Result is,
When I try this link -

```
http://sample.org/sat
```

it redirecting to

```
http://sample.org/example/?/sat
```

I am attaching whole .htaccess code down here,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?$1 [PT,L,QSA]


# Deny accessing below extensions
<Files ~ "(.json|.lock|.git|.bat|.md)">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
<Files robots.txt>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>

# Deny accessing dot files
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]

 # 301 Redirect URLs.
 Redirect 301 /sat http://sample.org/example
 Redirect 301 /gre http://sample.org/example
 Redirect 301 /ielts-sat http://sample.org/example
 Redirect 301 /ielts http://sample.org/example
```

Could anybody here help me, please?

Comment: If `sample.org` is _another_ http host, then you certainly should add those lines to the top of the file, _preceding_ internal rewriting rules.

Comment: its is same host

Comment: Then there is no need for absolute URLs, use relative ones instead which makes your rules more robust and portable. Still you should move those rules up so that they get applied to incoming requests _before_ the other rules.